# Adressing a specific bits in an array of std_logic vector in VHDL

Tags: arrays, vhdl, fpga, modelsim

Im new to VHDL.
my problem is that i cant seem to find the correct syntax for writing or reading from an array of std_logic_vector. i init the array as such :

```
 TYPE eleven_samples_in IS ARRAY ( 0 TO 10 ) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 87 DOWNTO 0 );
```

and i try addressing it as such :

```
odd: for i in 1 to 6 generate
   node: compare_level
       port map(
                input  => eleven_samples_in(i*2 - 1)(79 DOWNTO 0),
                output  => eleven_samples_out(i*2 - 1)(79 DOWNTO 0 )
               );
end generate odd;
```

Or :

```
 port map(
           input  => eleven_samples_in(i*2 - 1,79 DOWNTO 0),
           output  => eleven_samples_out(i*2 - 1,79 DOWNTO 0 )
         );
 end generate odd;
```

But i get an Errors such as :

> Error (10409): VHDL Type Conversion error at Median_Filter.vhd(45): converted type of object near text or symbol "eleven_samples_in" must match std_logic_vector type of target object

I searched the web and found nothing that works.

thank you very much for the help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you create a type eleven_samples_in, and use that directly. This is incorrect.

Instead:

```
type eleven_samples_in_type is array (0 to 11) of std_logic_vector(89 downto 0);
signal eleven_samples_in : eleven_samples_in_type;

...
```

Without knowing anything about your compare_levels component, thats as much help as I can be

Comment: Thank you very very much . that was the problem, and since i'm new it was hard to find the problem. any good tutorial on VHDL you can recommend ?

Comment: Most VHDL tutorials are terrible unfortunately (I'd love to be proved wrong). The language reference manual is a VERY in-depth way to understanding the language if you're really keen.

Comment: VHDL was designed by the US military to make contractors produce reliable circuits; it is the programming/modeling language of bureaucrats. The tutorials mostly come from Indian students whose schools lack the budget for hands-on circuit laboratory classes, making it the language of sloppy, careless bureaucrats. Fortunately you can go a long way with just a few constructs, since high-level programming often isn't really the point.

Answer (score 0):

To answer about the right syntax to access specific bits from an `array` of `std_logic_vector`, as I was wondering myself, it happens to be the first you suggested:

```
s_array(array_index)(vector_bit_index) -- for a single bit
```

or

```
s_array(array_index)(last_bit_index downto first_bit_index) -- for a range
```